# How to create a copy of a .clone( ) jquery object

Tags: jquery

I am trying to reuse / store an element with all the checkboxes but I'm running into problems using jquery's .clone(). For example:

```js
$('.test1').on('change', ':input', function() {
  $temp = $(".test1").clone()[0];
  $('#test2').html($temp);
  $('#test3').html($temp);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="test1">
  <input type="checkbox" checked> a<br/>
  <input type="checkbox" checked> b<br/>
</div>

<div>Test 2</div>
<div id="test2"></div>

<div>Test 3</div>
<div id="test3"></div>
```

When I make a change to .test1 it should save it to the variable and then take that variable and inset it into test2 and test3. But after it inserts it into test2, it removes it from there and inserts it only into test3.

Is there a work around or a better way to do this while also storing the states?

Answer (score 0):

the issue you are experiencing is likely due to the fact that you are replacing the contents of #test2 with the cloned element and then replacing the contents of #test3 with the same element, which removes it from #test2.
You can do this by calling .clone()

```
$('.test1').on('change', ':input', function() {
  var $temp = $(".test1").clone();
  $('#test2').html($temp.clone());
  $('#test3').html($temp.clone());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery is tricking you here, unfortunately. Inside of the `html` function, there is a check to see if the value passed is a string. In this case, it is not. The `[0]` of your clone is in fact an element.

You can double check this by using jQuery's own check:

```
console.log(typeof $temp === "string"); //false
```

As a result, the following code is used:

```
this.empty().append( value ); // where value is $temp
```

This means that the first call to `.html($temp)` appends the element, and the second call also appends the element. However, it is the same element in this case, and as such it is moved to the final call.

If you want to preserve the state, you will need a clone per insert. Inserting the html of the element will not preserve its checked or unchecked status.

```js
$('.test1').on('change', ':input', function() {
  $('#test2').html($(".test1").clone()[0]);
  $('#test3').html($(".test1").clone()[0]);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="test1">
  <input type="checkbox" checked> a<br/>
  <input type="checkbox" checked> b<br/>
</div>

<div>Test 2</div>
<div id="test2"></div>

<div>Test 3</div>
<div id="test3"></div>
```

Comment: Got ya, but in my example it was really more of a simplified version for readibility. So this does solve the question, it doesn't address how to store it. I'm actually going to be needing to store the entire element in a variable and reuse it as needed. So doing the clone at time of creation wouldn't really work. Surely there must be a way to store it.

Comment: @Robbie - It really depends on what you are storing, and where. There is absolutely a way to store the clone, however, in order for it to represent to current state of the element, it will need to be updated. That means the storage would need to be updated as well. It really depends on the implementation to sort out if that means the storage is even relevant. The crux of the issue is this: does the state of the input element matter? If yes, you can store the input element somewhere, and clone it from there each time you need it. If no, then you can simply take the html and reuse it at will.

Comment: Yeah, I was needing to store the state and the element (basically everything that is in the .clone() ). And then reuse the element with stored states as needed.

Comment: The element and state can be stored, but the stored copy wont be updated. That is fairly straightforward, and the only issue with the first version was that you would need to keep cloning in series.

Comment: Gotcha, I wouldn't need the stored copy to be updated. Just accessible as needed.

Comment: @Robbie - I see. So, essentially you are storing a structure for future use, and then needing it when called? See my edit at the bottom for a suggestion on how to approach that.